# How to align contents inside an iframe?

Tags: iframe

Your Browser Do not Support Iframe

How to align the content within this iframe?
for eg. I am cool is in the iframe and i want to align this in the center of the iframe. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using a source file for your `iframe` you can simply set it with a simple `<center>` tag in the target file.